# iPhone iOS 6 BonjourWeb Xcode 4.5 "Cancel Button Error

Tags: xcode, ios6, bonjour

I'm working with the source code for BonjourWeb using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5.
[BonjourWeb Source code for Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BonjourWeb/BonjourWeb.zip)

In BonjourWebAppDelegate.m, the setting for showCancelButton:YES in the "applicationDidFinishLaunching: application:" method causes the program to crash when the Cancel button is clicked in the app's browser with the error: 2012-10-27 13:07:45.309 BonjourWeb[1762:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSNetService dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:]: cannot convert nil to a dictionary.'

How can I rectify this to work properly?

Thank you.

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The call to the method causing the problem is not needed.